# Format an excel cell to only contain IDs

Tags: excel

I have an excel column that contains varying amount of users with their IDs in brackets next to them. I need a formula to just get the ID's separated by semi-colons. Everything I've tried so far has just given me #VALUE! or one of the IDs.
This is what the columns contain now, keep in mind each may have different users and differing amounts.
J**** P****** (g6****), B*** T****** (N4****), J*** V****** (A5****)
The ID's are one letter followed by 5 numbers.

Comment: are the IDs the ones inside the `()`

Comment: Yes they are, all in one cell. I can get one ID, but not multiple

Comment: to get them all in one cell you will need vba, or use helper columns that pulls it apart one into its own cell then concatenate.

Comment: Provide some dummy data without *.

Comment: IF you have Office365 / Excel 2016, you can use the `TEXTJOIN` function.

Comment: John Smith (g12345), Bill Turner (N43210), Jim Johnson (A78912)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this *relatively* easily using the Find/Replace keyboard function.

Copy the text of the cell that currently contains your raw text, and paste that entire text into a cell where you'd like your destination/extracted text to end up.

Then highlight the destination cell, and press CTRL+f.

Click the tab labeled "Replace".

In the "Find What" field, enter `)*(` (three characters total).

In the "Replace with" field, enter `;` (one character only).

Again, with the destination cell only highlighted, then click on the "Replace All" button.

Finally, manually deleted the first name and opening paraenthesis, and also the final closing paranthesis.

You will be left with a semicolon-separated list of just your 6-character IDs, with a minimum of manual keystrokes necessary.

Comment: That worked rather well, didn't even think of the )*(, problem with deleting the first name is that there at 1600+ rows

Comment: Ahh, In that case, you can just repeat the CTRL+f portion with "*(" in the Find What Field, and the Replace With field left blank, and then finally one more time with ")" in the Find What Field and the Replace With field left blank.